# Join 2 Collection: Order and Products and group by _id, total amount (quantity * price) Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I want to Join 2 Collection: Order and Products and group by _id, total amount (quantity * price)
Collection("Products")

```
{ "_id" : "P001", "name" : "Product A", "description" : "for Việt Nam", "price" : 900 },
{ "_id" : "P002", "name" : "Product B", "description" : "for Việt Nam", "price" : 800 },
{ "_id" : "P003", "name" : "Product C", "description" : "for USA", "price" : 1000 },
{ "_id" : "P004", "name" : "Product D", "description" : "for Japan", "price" : 1500 },
{ "_id" : "P005", "name" : "Product E", "description" : "for Japan", "price" : 1100 },
```

Collection("Order")

```
{ "_id" : "8001", "userId" : "U01", "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-01T00:00:00Z"), "products" : [ { "productId" : "P001", "quantity" : 1 }, { "productId" : "P003", "quantity" : 3 } ] },
{ "_id" : "8002", "userId" : "U02", "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-01T00:00:00Z"), "products" : [ { "productId" : "P003", "quantity" : 5 }, { "productId" : "P004", "quantity" : 2 } ] },
{ "_id" : "8003", "userId" : "U01", "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-02T00:00:00Z"), "products" : [ { "productId" : "P002", "quantity" : 2 }, { "productId" : "P004", "quantity" : 5 } ] },
{ "_id" : "8004", "userId" : "U03", "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-03T00:00:00Z"), "products" : [ { "productId" : "P001", "quantity" : 4 }, { "productId" : "P005", "quantity" : 3 } ] },
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "8003" }, "thanhtien" : 9100, "Số mặt hàng đặt" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "8002" }, "thanhtien" : 8000, "Số mặt hàng đặt" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "8004" }, "thanhtien" : 6900, "Số mặt hàng đặt" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "8001" }, "thanhtien" : 3900, "Số mặt hàng đặt" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

- First `$unwind` to acces each obejct into `products` array.
- Then join collections using `$lookup`.
- Get the first element of the result (comparing by IDs should return one document, otherwise you can use `$unwind` again).
- Add a field called `total` to get the total value.
- And `$group` the values again to get the desired result.

```
db.Order.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Products",
      "localField": "products.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "result": {
        "$arrayElemAt": ["$result", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "total": {
        "$multiply": ["$products.quantity", "$result.price"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "thanhtien": {
        "$sum": "$total"
      },
      "Số mặt hàng đặt": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kc1evWct558)